# Problems with ScriptManager, ASP.NET Web Forms (4.5), Visual Studio 2013 Prof., AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2013, webforms, webresource.axd

I have the problem that I cannot use the ScriptManager in my ASP.NET Web Forms (4.5) anymore. It always throws the following critical JavaScript error messages (SCRIPT1002 is telling a syntax error) in Internet Explorer 11:

[image] 
[image]

I tried to solve the problem with https://pavanarya.wordpress.com/2011/page/11/ and found out that WebForms.js shall cause the problem regarding to the decrypted WebResource.axd URL of the first error message (see above).

Furthermore, I found out that the error vanishes if I remove the line

[image] 
from my Layout.Master file. All error messages vanish, but AJAX elements like TreeView (I also use UpdatePanel and Calendar) do not work anymore then, too.

I also tried the Script Resource Viewer from http://www.dotneti18n.com/Downloads.aspx via 
http://www.guysmithferrier.com/post/2007/07/Script-Resource-Viewer.aspx. But the funny thing is that even the Script Resource Viewer implements the line

[image] 
which exactly causes the same error as before, and so it is not a real help for me.

It must be some global problem in the whole project since it does not accepts any ScriptManager (no matter in which ASPX file) anymore. Does someone know that problem?
Many thanks in advance!!!

Remark: The Firefox Browser does not throw an error message, but it does not show the TreeView correctly, too. All images (ImageSet) of the TreeView are missing and the Web Browser displays text instead of the images. I also use a Chart (System.Web.DataVisualization) in the Web project, it was the last item which was added there. I use C#.

Comment: I have created a new web project with a simple ScriptManager, the problem does not occur there. I will try to copy the whole project in a new one. Hopefully, I will find the error in this way. Because I have already invested many hours to find the problem.

Comment: I could only solve the problem by creating a new project and by copying everything from the old to the new project. Everything works fine now. It told me that the project datei (*.sln) changed and nothing more, I would think that something in the project files was wrong or corrupt which caused that error, maybe in connection with the NuGet packages. The error was not inside the code or all known configuration files, it seems it was somewhere deeply hidden in the project which was not visible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to put this as comment. So I will put it as Answer:

Use ToolScriptManager instead of ScriptManager.

Comment: Many thanks, I could solve it by copying it into a new project now. But I will uprate your answer. Maybe I will have the same problem later again, maybe it will be useful then. Many thanks to you!!!